# Fluent NHibernate Newbie: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate

I'm in the early stages of building out a database with Fluent NHibernate. I implemented a unit-of-work pattern in ASP.NET MVC 3 to let NHibernate update my database schema for me. To insert/update my initial data, I have a `Database` controller with an `Update` action that tries to `SaveOrUpdate(...)` a `User` entity (the administrator user) into the `Users` table.

After manually deleting all user records via Visual Studio and re-running my `Update` action to repopulate the `Users` table, I receive the following `NHibernate.StaleObjectStateException` exception:

```
Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was
incorrect): [Invoicer.Data.Entities.User#3105248d-ca91-4c64-bf8f-9ebb017943b7]

Line 26:        {
Line 27:            if (_transaction.IsActive)
Line 28:                _transaction.Commit();
Line 29:        }
```

Note: the saved or updated user ID is a Guid with the value above (3105...).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Solved with Mapping

NHibernate was assigning User IDs (Guid) for me using the Guid comb method. Manually specifying the ID was tripping up the mapping. I prefer to assign these IDs myself, so I changed the `User` entity ID mapping to be manually assigned in my `UserMap` class:

```
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
```

Comment: This can also happen when you try and set the ID of an entity when creating it. NH should define the ID using the mapping rules.

Answer (score 0):

This error also occurs when the changed context and you if you PK is character.

The Solution is apply Trim() in PK when `Update(data, data.code.Trim())`;